# connect MySql database in WHM(phpmyadmin) to node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin, cpanel

As a team, we are using node.js to setup the database connection with Mysql in Cpanel.

I did not make the database, but I know the host, user,password, database name, and port. However, in app.js, although I put all the code needed to connect to the database, it fails all the time.

Here is my code in app.js.

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');

// creating a connection to the db
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'myUsername',
  password: 'myPassword',
  database: 'myDatabase',
  port:3306
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if(err){
    console.log('Error connecting to DB');
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connection established');
});
```

Comment: Port 3306 is the default, unless configured otherwise, but will it connect if you try using only the host, user, and password?  Also, see if using `host: '127.0.0.1'` makes any difference.

Comment: It doesn't make any change..

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the error?

By the way, you dont need to do a con.connect.

Even you use the `var con = mysql.createConnection`, con is a mysql resource.

Simple do this:

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');

// creating a connection to the db
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'myUsername',
  password: 'myPassword',
  database: 'myDatabase',
  port:3306
});

con.query('SELECT * FROM table', function(err, results) {
  if(err){
    console.log('Query error: ', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: I am just getting the massage 'Error connecting to DB'.

Comment: Change: `console.log('Error connecting to DB');` to `console.log(err)`